# localized Microsoft Ajax CDN reference not working in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, localization, webforms, scriptmanager

In vs2010, I start a new project > asp.net web application and get presented with the new default webapp. I add a scriptmanager tag, with CDN set to enabled and as a result it tries to contact Microsoft's CDN at ajax.microsoft.com, and not only that, it tries to load the localized files from a url that doesn't exist.

Anybody got an idea where I can change this for the default web application template or in the solution itself?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smgr" ScriptMode="Auto"  EnableCdn="true" runat="server">
```

tries to loads the files from: http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.nl.js

Or does the EnableCdn mean that I have to manually map all the .js (incl the microsoft ones) ?
For the record, I'm using VS2010 with all the latest updates.

Comment: It seems that they [renamed their service](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#ajaxmicrosoftcom_renamed_to_ajaxaspnetcdncom_8). The strange thing is, you say you are using VS2010 and it should work properly.

Comment: True, they changed it to ajax.aspnetcdn.com but the localization is the bigger issue. On the CDN the localization is stored as a subfolder and not as a .culture in the js name.

So even if I were to somehow point to microsoft's new CDN, the scripts still wouldn't get loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer by email from Damian Edwards, so I thought and post it here so if anybody else runs into this, they know the reason why...

> Sorry for the delay in replying. We don’t currently host localized versions of the JavaScript files on our CDN. It is “on the list” to get done, but is not a trivial task. I hope to have it completed in the next few months.
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience.
>   Damian

Answer (score 1):

Damian Edwards is looking into this now.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome news, if he needs some add info, screenshots or testbed - he's more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off localization or globalization for the Scriptmanager:

Setting **EnableScriptLocalization**=false will resolve your issue.

Comment: You are right, and I went for that solution, but it should have worked with localization. So I'm still unsure if its a configuration, installation or framework issue.

I've replicated it on several machines so I'm fairly sure its not a configuration or installation issue. And try to poke some VS peeps to verify it's a framework thing but no answer yet...